# Python2.7 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in dataframe values

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding, pyspark

With Pyspark,I tried to create a function that will return proporly the content of a dataframe.

```
def format(dataframe,take=100):
    header = "\t".join(dataframe.columns)
    spacer = "\t".join(["--" for c in dataframe.columns])
    data = ["\t".join([unicode(a.asDict()[c]) for c in dataframe.columns]) for a in dataframe.take(take)]
    return "\n".join([header, spacer] + data)
```

But, in some values of the dataframe, there is a non ascii characters that throw the **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)** Exception

I tried to add encode("utf8") function to the dataframe but doesn't work,

To more clarify the problem, here is an example:

```
df= spark.createDataFrame([
            [1, "value_1"],
            [2, "value_1"],
            [3, "value_2"],
            [4, "valué_2"]
        ], ['key', 'value']
        )
```

When I call my function ,I get last line malformed

```
print show_function(df)
+---+--------+
|key|   value|
+---+--------+
|  1| value_1|
|  2| value_1|
|  3| value_2|
|  4|valuÃ©_2|
+---+--------+
```

Any help please
Thanks

Comment: You're mixing `unicode` and `str` values.  Try to use `unicode` consistently within your application.

Comment: @snakecharmerb ,thank you for your response, I changed str to unicode and it works but It didn't show correctly the values

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I edit the post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some researchs in other posts, I find the solution,
I added the encoding(Latin-1) decoding("UTF8") functions.

```
data = ["\t".join([unicode(a.asDict()[c]).encode('latin-1').decode("utf8") for c in dataframe.columns]) for a in dataframe.take(take)]
```

Now,the function works fine and properly affect the dataframe results to a string to be shown after